# How to reintegrate a feature branch to a copy of the trunk in SVN?

Tags: svn

The traditional way of working with feature branches is illustrated in following ascci image.

```
       FB o-------------------o
         /                     \
        /copy                   \ reintegrate 
       /                         \     
TRUNK-o---------------------------o---
```

Actually the reintegration of my feature branch needs a lot of testing and should also work on a continuous build server. That is the reason why I need to do the reintegration into the trunk in 2 steps. This scenario is shown here:

```
enter code here
       FB    o--------------------o
            /                      \ reintegrate (problems here :-( )
           /                        \
          /               FB2    o---o----------------o
         /copy                  /                      \
        /                 copy /                        \ reintegrate
       /                      /                          \
TRUNK-o----------------------o----------------------------o--
```

Unfortunately I cannot reintegrate the feature branch into the copy of the trunk. SVN says that the root path of the trunk copy files is missing. Before going further with the analysis of the errors, I would like to know if in general a reintegration can take place between a branch and a *copy* of the trunk.

UPDATE
I found out how to reintegrate a feature branch into a copy of the trunk:

```
       FB    o--------------------o
            /                      \ (2)reintegrate into the local trunk copy
           /                        \
          /                          \        FB2    o----o---------------o
         /copy                        \             /     ^                \
        /                              \   (3)copy /      |                 \ reintegrate 
       /                                \         /       |                  v
TRUNK-o----------------------------o-----\-------o--------|-------------------o--  
                                    \     |               |
                            (1)checkout  /                |(4) svn switch to FB                            
                                      v v                 |    + svn commit
                                      []-------------------
                             fresh checked out 
                             local working copy
```

Comment: Can you please explain the approach that worked for you in detail? Shouldn't in step (4) we should switch to FB2?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use merge, with the good range of revision number. (I think that reintegrates only work on the actual trunk)

The [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/index.en.html) may be useful to you on the subject of merge and branches.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is an SVN [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging).

What you need to do is basically to merge all the **differences** between point A and B below (see diagram) into the FB2 branch.

You can run the following command (assuming your working copy is in the FB2 branch):

```
svn merge -rA:B <url_of_FB_branch> .
```

where `A` and `B` are the revision numbers at point `A` and `B` in the diagram below:

```
     FB    A o--------------------o B
            /                      \ reintegrate (problems here :-( )
           /                        \
          /               FB2    o---o----------------o
         /copy                  /                      \
        /                 copy /                        \ reintegrate
       /                      /                          \
TRUNK-o----------------------o----------------------------o--
```

To get the revision number for `A`:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy <url_of_FB_branch>
```

and grab the smallest revision number (ie, earliest) from the list

For `B`, it's easier. Assuming that you want to grab the latest change from FB, just use the `HEAD` keyword as the revision number for `B`

Comment: Sure that merge a range of revisions will help, however this will issue a lot of conflicts that should be resolved manually. Since I merged all my trunk changes to the feature branch during the last 4 months of work once per week and solved all those conflicts, merging now back without the reintegrate option is nightmare of repetitive work.